# ps1 script asks for InputObject upon run

Tags: powershell

I am emailing a CSV file via Powershell and it won't run without asking for an InputObject.

I'm not sure how to populate this parameter.   I should point out that I can "Enter" past the prompt without values and it works properly. But this is supposed to be automation. :)

```
$SQLServer = "server"
$SQLDBName = "dbname"
$uid ="uid"
$pwd = "pwd"

$SqlQuery = 'SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TABLE'


$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "string"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation "C:\Testing\Stuff.csv"
$SqlConnection.Close() 

$file = 'C:\Testing\stuff.csv'  

Export-Csv -Force -NoTypeInformation -Path $file 

$options = @{
'SmtpServer' = "mail.company.com" 
'To' = "Me <me@company.com>" 
'From' = "<donotreply@company.com>" 
'Subject' = "Stuff" 
'Body' = "text about stuff" 
'Attachments' = $file 
}

Send-MailMessage @options
```

I expect it to work without any user prompts.

Comment: Where does export-csv get its input?

Comment: I just added the query code

Comment: You're not actually exporting anything to the file on the second export which is why it's prompting. Get rid of that and you should be good

Comment: Ah that worked!  Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not actually exporting anything on that second `Export-csv`, that's what is prompting you. If you run `Export-Csv` without any input, it will prompt you for the input. If you remove that, you should be good.

```
$SQLServer = "server"
$SQLDBName = "dbname"
$uid ="uid"
$pwd = "pwd"

$SqlQuery = 'SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TABLE'


$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "string"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation "C:\Testing\Stuff.csv"
$SqlConnection.Close() 

$file = 'C:\Testing\stuff.csv'  

****REMOVE THIS****
Export-Csv -Force -NoTypeInformation -Path $file 
*******************

$options = @{
'SmtpServer' = "mail.company.com" 
'To' = "Me <me@company.com>" 
'From' = "<donotreply@company.com>" 
'Subject' = "Stuff" 
'Body' = "text about stuff" 
'Attachments' = $file 
}

Send-MailMessage @options
```